# Eloquent model between dates format d.m.Y

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.1

I have column "exp_date"  with type of string, format of column is d.m.Y.
I want to get records between two dates.

I am trying like with this code:

```
$start = '10.09.2016';
$end = '20.10.2018';

$company->records()->whereBetween('exp_date', [$start, $end])->get();
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Laravel $q->where() between dates](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24824624/laravel-q-where-between-dates)

Comment: @maiorano84 not exactly like [Laravel $q->where() between dates]http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24824624/laravel-q-where-between-dates

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply use [carbon package](https://github.com/briannesbitt/Carbon) which  extends the native PHP DateTime class.

**EXAMPLE 1 : DATABASE COLUMN TYPE IS SET TO `date` OR `dateTime`**
    $start = '10.09.2016';
    $end = '20.10.2018';

```
$start = Carbon::createFromFormat('d-m-Y',  $start)->toDateTimeString(); 
$end = Carbon::createFromFormat('d-m-Y',  $end)->toDateTimeString();
```

Then create query

```
$company = Records::where(function($q){
    $q->where('exp_date', '<=',$start );
    $q->where('exp_date', '>', $end);

});

$company->get();
```

**EXAMPLE 2 : DATABASE COLUMN TYPE IS SET TO `varchar`**

Here you will have to first of all covert existing table column via migrations .
Before modifying a column, be sure to add the `doctrine/dbal` dependency to your `composer.json` file.

`php artisan make:migration update_exp_to_records_table --table=records`

Edit the migration file , add below relevant to your table names

```
Schema::table('records', function ($table) {
    $table->string('expire')->date()->change();
});
```

Run only this specific migration
Then use example 1 above in your controller function.

Comment: But than database record also should be in Date format?

Comment: Yes let me update it when using string/varchar type collumn ,give a few minutes

Answer (score 0):

With raw query you should use something like this:

```
SELECT * FROM table_name 
WHERE UNIX_TIMESTAMP(col_name) > UNIX_TIMESTAMP(:start) 
  AND UNIX_TIMESTAMP(col_name) < UNIX_TIMESTAMP(:end)
```

You don't have to use `UNIX_TIMESTAMP()` for `$start` and `$end` value with MySQL just `strtotime()` in PHP.

**Note:** If MySQL do not type your string into unix timestamp, maybe you need to use function [`CAST()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/cast-functions.html).

Documentation:[`UNIX_TIMESTAMP()` in MySQL](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_unix-timestamp), [`strtotime()` in PHP](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php)