# Getting specific date ranges from database in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I need to get results from a DB divided by dates such as today, yesterday, this week, last week, etc.

I can easily do this with whereRaw and some SQL:

```
whereRaw('Date(created_at) = CURDATE()')->get();
```

I wonder if there is an easier, proper way to do this with Eloquent.

Comment: Your raw SQL does not filter by range.

Comment: @AlexBlex This was just an example of how to get today, obviously when I want to get a range I will expand it.

Comment: If http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24824624/laravel-q-where-between-dates ,  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33361628/laravel-eloquent-date-range, etc don't give you a hint, refer to the docs https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/queries#where-clauses?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Laravel $q->where() between dates](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24824624/laravel-q-where-between-dates)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could create a scope for a particular class like this:

```
public function scopeYourQuery($query, $user) {
    return $query->where('user_id', $user->id)->orderBy('created_at', 'desc')->first();
}
```

This just gets the first item of a descending ordered list ordered by created_at date per user.

If you wanted something that was between date ranges? You just pass in your date and extend it a bit with some PHP, maybe something like this would work:

```
public function scopeSomeDateQuery($query, $fetch_date, $user)
{
    //clone the users chosen month - so we can make the range until the following month
    $also_fetch_date = clone $fetch_date;
    $next_month = $also_fetch_date->addMonth();
    $next_month = $next_month->format('Y-m-d');
    $fetch_date = $fetch_date->format('Y-m-d');
    //return the query for the monthname
    return $query->orderBy('created_date')->where('created_date', '>=', $fetch_date)->where('created_date', '<', $next_month)->where('user_id', $user->id);
}
```

This would look in a monthly range (per user) to get an ordered list of items with a created_date in that range.

Comment: I was asking if there was a ready eloquent way to achieve this but since it seems there is not this is a good start. Thanks.

Comment: Yeah, not that I am aware of - I think you have to craft the query yourself with your input. If you DO find a better way - let me know! I run up against similar queries often!